# JavaScript error on logging in

Tags: javascript, facebook, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

In iOS 5, when a user attempts to share a link using the Facebook API, they are prompted to log in, but then the resulting page returns this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> window.location.href="fbconnect:\/\/ success#_=_";
</script>
```

The only option is to close the window. If the user then attempts to share a link a second time, it works.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked out my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932087/facebook-ios-sdk-strange-effects-in-writing-to-status/8258041?

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem. It is an issue with iOS 4.2 as well. The javascript I get in return has a lillte different success-statement. Mine is
''... success?post_id=MyFbUserID_253268854729889#*=*"; ...''.
I do use the facebook iOS SDK e9df551 from Nov 03, 2011.

See posting [Facebook Feed Dialog returns a unhandled JavaScript including post_id that crashes iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236359/facebook-feed-dialog-returns-a-unhandled-javascript-including-post-id-that-crash)