# Facebook Feed Dialog returns a unhandled JavaScript including post_id that crashes iOS app

Tags: javascript, objective-c, facebook, dialog

I try to use Facebook's Feed Dialog.
According to the examples on the Facebook Developer's web pages I coded two classes *MyAppModelClass* and *MyViewCntrl*, see below.

Compilation runs without errors or warnings!
And the iOS app hangs only the first time it is ran.

When I call *[MyViewCntrl aMethod]* the **first time**
    - The user has to login with eMail and password
    - After login posting to the users wall can be edited
    - After clicking "share" button on the feed dialog I get a grey view displayed and the iOS app hangs.

The view shows text that says:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href="fbconnect:\/\/success?
post_id=<MyFbUserID>_253268854729889#_=_";
</script>
```

I thing the second number at post_id is a access token, but I am not sure.

- I **do not** get a NSLog from one of the FBDialofDelegate's
  methods, (*[MyAppModelClass dialogDidComplete]*,
      *[MyAppModelClass dialogDidNotComplete]*, …)  at console!
- The posting appears at the users wall

If I stop the iOS app in the iphone simulator (home button) and i Xcode (stop button) and
then restart the app on the iPhone simulator I do not get asked for authentication.
And I **do not** get this javascript returned, everything works fine then.

What can I do to handle, avoid or get rid of the javascript returned during the first run?

See code outline below ...

---

**MyAppModelClass.h**

```
#import "Facebook.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"
#import "FBDialog.h"

@interface MyAppModelClass :  NSObject <FBDialogDelegate, FBSessionDelegate>  {

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook* facebook;
}
```

**MyAppModelClass.m**

```
#import "MyAppModelClass.h"

@synthesize facebook;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBDialogDelegate


- (void) dialogDidComplete: (FBDialog*) dialog {
   NSLog(@"<FBDialogDelegate>.dialogDidComplete: %@", dialog);
}


- (void) dialogCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL*) url {
   NSLog(@"<FBDialogDelegate>.dialogDidCompleteWithURL: %@", url);
}


- (void) dialogDidNotComplete:(FBDialog*) dialog {
   NSLog(@"<FBDialogDelegate>.dialogDidNotComplete: %@", dialog);
}

- (void)dialogDidNotCompleteWithUrl:(NSURL*) url {
    NSLog(@"<FBDialogDelegate>.dialogDidNotCompleteWithUrl: %@", url);
}


- (void)dialog:(FBDialog*)dialog didFailWithError:(NSError*) error{
    NSLog(@"<FBDialogDelegate>.didFailWithError: %@", dialog);

}
```

---

**MyViewCntrl.h**

```
#import "MyAppModelClass.h"

- (void) aMethod;
```

**MyViewCntrl.m**

```
#import "MyViewCntrl.h"


- (void) aMethod {
NSMutableDictionary* myParameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc];
          initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"1234567", @"app_id",  
                                    @"touch", @"display",
     @"http://myWebSite.de/pics/AppIcon.jpg", @"picture",
                      @"http://myWebSite.de", @"link",  
                         @"It's my web site", @"caption",
               @"Visit my personal web site", @"description",
                                    @"false", @"show_error", nil];

[ptrMyAppModelClass facebook] dialog: @"feed"
                           andParams: myParameters
                         andDelegate: ptrMyAppModelClass];
}
```

Comment: Kinda good news:  
I still get this unwanted javascript view in return, but it does not crash my iOS app any more. It turned out some pictures were missing. With this pictures there is a (x), means close-button in the upper left corner of that view. With this Close-button the user can close this additional view and can go on with the app.  
  
How do I close this view automatically so the user does not see it?

Comment: See these postings as well:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987431/javascript-error-on-logging-in/8255298#8255298  
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7932087/facebook-ios-sdk-strange-effects-in-writing-to-status/8258041#8258041